# Interface Builder appears blurry on retina display in Xcode 6.3

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, xcode6.3

I just recently downloaded the latest public release of Xcode (6.3) and I noticed the storyboard for my app is now low res on my Retina MacBook Pro. Images, text and standard UI elements all appear blurry. On the actual device everything looks fine and code still looks sharp its just while working in the Interface Builder.

Has anybody else noticed this and figured out a way to fix it? This is happening to me in both Swift and Objective-C projects including in Apple's sample projects (Master-Detail Application and etc).

Comment: Noticed this, too - seems like everything renders in @1x and gets upscaled on retina display.

Comment: I have the same problem as well, it's as maxkonovalov said, its probably rendering everything @1x even default buttons and labels :(

Comment: Experiencing the same here. This is frustrating. They keep on endorsing retina then this.

Comment: This is the second major bug in XCode 6.3 (the other one is described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29542356/xcode-6-3-crashes-when-navigating-from-storyboard-to-other-swift-1-2-file)

Comment: I just downloaded 6.3 and noticed this. Very frustrating!

Comment: Who the f...reak made me upgrade to 6.3?.......

Comment: I see this in Xcode as well as Time Machine on my Mac. The issue seems to correlate with OS X 10.10.3 coming out -- I remain unconvinced that it's just Xcode.

Comment: The third major bug in XCode 6.3 (another is builds) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30331302/xcode-6-3-2-unable-to-build-or-run-projects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just installed Xcode version 6.3.2 and this issue appears to have been fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I submitted this as a bug report, and Apple responded by saying that it is the desired appearance. They did not give an explanation, that was all they said.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be related to a bug in the newest iOS SDK, and as a workaround, they've forced Interface Builder to render everything at 1x. Currently, there doesn't seem to be any solution to this annoying problem other than to wait.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried re-installation of the same version? That helped once.
Alternatively, can upgrade to newer version, too.