# Xcode 6.3.2 unable to build or run projects

Tags: xcode6

After upgrading to Xcode 6.3.2 I'm unable to build/run, analyse, profile project. Even project clean functionality looks broken. Does any body experienced similar problem and know how to fix it?

Comment: Same issue here.  It may be related to the targets:  xCode now just wants to target the Mac though I'm building for IOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling with this problem for couple of hours I have finally found solution. In my case Xcode **Derived Data location** was set to custom folder and it was the origin of the problem. After changing Xcode Derived Data location to default one everything back to normal.

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to go away when you go download and install the new command line tools for 6.3.2.