# Swift background disproportionate in Storyboard

Tags: image, swift, background, storyboard

I have a problem with a background image in a controller .

I set an image directly from a storyboard with ImageView , but this seems to be disproportionate and grainy on the storyboard , but then when you launch the app screen appears proportionate.

That makes me hard to graphic design because I see the storyboard no depreciation corresponding to reality

What can be ?

I hope I was clear enough

thanks

Comment: What xcode are you on? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29541449/interface-builder-appears-blurry-on-retina-display-in-xcode-6-3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Go on your storyboard, select one of your view controller
2. Right panel > Size inspector > Select freeform in simulated size
3. Put the size you want

Note with autolayout you are designing "responsive" interface, that's why the screen is bigger because it's could be an interface which can fit both an iPad screen or Iphone, also a question of landscape/not-landscape.

I don't recommend to change this mode then, or only if you are building an app for a specific screen only.

Also, by default the layout is set to Any Width / Any Height that's correspond to all layouts possible but you can change this in the bottom of the middle panel.